# Cant figure out how to use lists in the constructor and edit the value

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, constructor

This is my blueprint script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Blueprint

{
     public string craftedItemName;
     public string craftedUnits;
     public int minNeeded;
     public string neededItemsUnits;
     public List<string> resourcesList = new List<string>();

     public Blueprint(string name,string craftunits,int minneed,string needunits,List<string> resList)
     {
        craftedItemName = name;
        craftedUnits = craftunits;
        minNeeded = needunits;
        neededItemsUnits = needunits;
        resourcesList = resList;
     }
```

And in my crafting script i have

```
//other code
public Blueprint GlBeBLP = new("Glass Beaker","Units",1,"Kg",*Here i dont know how to say Glass*);
//other code
```

I know i could just use a string because its just one item but i need it to be a list for future items that will need more than one resource any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried resList.Add("Glass") but didnt work, i have tried just glass and converting it to a list with a cast but didnt work and didnt expect it to but yeah i cant figure it out alone and have searched on the web but cant find one that helps with my case.

Comment: You should do something along the lines of:
`resourcesList = new List<string>() { "Glass" };` in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass in a new `List<string>` as your last parameter of your constructor, with one item, "Glass", so you could do so in the following way:

```
   public Blueprint GlBeBLP = new("Glass Beaker","Units",1,"Kg", 
        new List<string> { "Glass" });
```

Comment: @blessingeoduck If this answer has been helpful, you can show your appreciation by marking it as the accepted answer.